# about file io functions IN C

Tags: c, file, input

i am dealing with the file io functions,can any one explain me the use & working of the statement 2,in the following code,here i want to enter string,&then want to write it on a disk.....

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sttring.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char s[80];
    fp=fopen("noname00.cpp","w");
    while(strlen(gets(s))>0) /*parenthesis now at correct place*/ /*purpose of this statement */
    {
        fputs(s,fp);
        fputs("\n",fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Simple but to the point help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get this code from? It should not even compile, the include directive has a typo, and `strlen` of a boolean is also not legal.

Comment: Also, [gets()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gets) is **dangerous** and has been deprecated [for ages now](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gets). Consider using something safer, or at least falling back to `fgets()`.

Comment: Do not use `gets`. It can't be used safely. And it's been removed from [the next language standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf).

Comment: @Redx i am studying 'let us C' by yashwant kanetkar,

Comment: @Frederic yes but look at the parenthesis. It does `gets(s) > 0` then the parenthesis.

Comment: @RedX, yup, you're absolutely right, I didn't see this at first (and unfortunately removed my previous comment when I realized it).

Comment: @Alfred throw the book away. It seems to be really bad.

Comment: @ Alfred Nobel yes nobal throw that book away.The author is too lazy to update the book! Modern compilers do not compile the code written above and given in that book !!

Comment: @suhail gupta thanks............:D,then suggest me something better than the best book for it

Comment: @ Alfred Nobel i recently bought effective c++ but that is not for beginners.You can go with complete reference,and then should refer effective c++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which one exactly is statement 2? `char s[80];`? It simply declares and defines a character array of size 80.

If you mean statement 2 is `while(strlen(gets(s)>0))`, it doesn't look correct to me. strlen() accepts a `const char *` as its argument but you are specifying it an integer instead: `gets(s) > 0`.

Also, never use `gets()` because http://c-faq.com/stdio/getsvsfgets.html

Also, get a copy of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language and study.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the statement is to test for just a "return" to break out of the loop.  Otherwise the use can continue to enter multiple lines and add more than one line to the file.  If you really only want to allow a single line, the while {} can be removed.